# I cannot find certain fields on the MAGENTO database

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I was trying to find this fields because i want to obtain all the products and then, make a query but i was not able to do that(they dont appear in the database diagram for Magento 1.9):

```
sku, code_brand, code_business_unit, code_line, code_group, code_business, min_sale_qty
```

This is the diagram:

[image: diagram]
https://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png

I only found the fields **"SKU"** and **"min_sale_qty"**. What happened to the others?

Do these fields : code_brand, code_business_unit, code_line, code_group, code_business even exist or they were created by someone?

[image]

Anyway, i am using MYSQL connected to the MAGENTO database.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `code_brand, code_business_unit, code_line, code_group, code_business` are custom product attributed that you added right?

When you add a custom attribute, Magento add a row in the table `eav_attribute`.
There we can find `attribute_id` and `backend_type`.

For example if `code_brand` is a integer the backend_type should be `int`. So in `catalog_product_entity_int` we can find rows with the same attribute_id set in the eav_attribute table.

Here you are a sumple query to search that:

`SELECT 
    *
FROM
    catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE
    attribute_id IN (
    SELECT 
            attribute_id
    FROM
        eav_attribute
    WHERE
        attribute_code = 'code_brand'
    );`